# Async Await with Redux doesn't seem to work

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, react-redux

I'm trying to implement Async/Await function in my redux, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Actions.js**

```
export function getUserCart(token) {
  return async dispatch => {
    await axios
      .get(`${apiUrl}/user/cart`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({

        console.log(GET_USER_CART_SUCCESS);
          type: GET_USER_CART_SUCCESS,
          cart: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_USER_CART_FAILED,
          error: error.response.data
        });
      });
  };
}
```

**Reducers.js**

```
case GET_USER_CART_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: action.cart,
        type: action.type
      };
```

**Component.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("before");
    this.props.getUserCart(this.props.user.idToken);
    console.log("after");
  }
```

The console returned :

```
before
after
GET_USER_CART_SUCCESS
```

However, if I do this

```
async componentDidMount() {
    console.log("before");
    await this.props.getUserCart(this.props.user.idToken);
    console.log("after");
  }
```

it returns the correct output :

```
before
GET_USER_CART_SUCCESS
after
```

I'm not comfortable with adding async and await in my component's function, it shouldn't be that way either. Is there anything I'm missing from my actions.js?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: do you really need to run something inside `componentDidMount` only after `getUserCart` is finished? Any way you make it would not stop `render()` from running so it's better not to relying on "`getUserCart` is has completed at this point". So idiomatically it's rather wrong turn, you better add some code in reducer itself or action body if you need react on data is loaded.

Comment: From what I understand, am I not supposed to have the second result for the first componentDidMount? And I'm using the code in componentDidMount only to make a point. What I'm trying to do is POST update on trigger and then GET the updated result to the component using the async await method.

Comment: Why are you not comfortable with adding async and await in component's function?